# Директива #pragma не работает. Си

Tags: c, препроцессор, директива

есть простой код:

```
# include <stdio.h>
void function_before_main();
void function_after_main();
# pragma startup function_before_main 64
# pragma exit function_after_main 65
int main()
{
    printf("MAIN");
    return 0;
}           
void function_before_main(){
    printf("BEFORE MAIN");
}
void function_after_main(){
    printf("AFTER MAIN");
}
```

Но не работает ни exit ни startup. Выводит только MAIN. Компилятор gcc, запускаю с cmd.

Comment: GCC не поддерживает `#pragma startup` и  `#pragma exit`. Откуда вы это взяли?

Comment: Упс:// Да в лабораторной в универе задание. А какой компилятор поддерживает?

Comment: Это что-то из Борланда...

Comment: @AnT в методичке pragma размещена среди других директив, которые работают: define, ifndef, if и т.д. Как можно использовать в обычном Си?

Comment: http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/pragma

Comment: И? Существование директивы `#pragma` никто не оспаривает. Но в вашем случае проблема не в самой `#pragma`, а в том, что идет после `#pragma`: вот эти ваши `startup` и `exit`. Директива `#pragma` для того и придумана, чтобы через нее записывать в код всякий компиляторно-зависимый мусор (который потом больше нигде не будет работать). Вот эти ваши `startup` и `exit` - это и есть тот самый компиляторно-зависимый мусор, который в GCC будет просто игнорироваться.

Answer (score 0):

В референсе для GCC 4.3.4. нечто подобное есть только в таком виде:

```
5.52.5 Solaris Pragmas

fini (function [, function ]...)
    This pragma causes each listed function to be called after main, or during shared
    module unloading, by adding a call to the .fini section.

init (function [, function ]...)
    This pragma causes each listed function to be called during initialization (before
    main) or during shared module loading, by adding a call to the .init section.
```

Но ведь это только для Соларис!